how to check which quota is needed in Google Cloud
I am writing a biblebot that lets GenAI read the bible and is then available to answer queries.
Doing it on Google Cloud using the Generative Language API.
In my python script, the "generate_content" function comes back with the error message:
google.api_core.exceptions.ResourceExhausted: 429 Resource has been exhausted (e.g. 
check quota).

How can I find out what quota has been exhausted? In Cloud Console, in the Generative Language API management I see no quota use at all. Looking into Cloud Logging, I do not find any warning or info.
How can I find out what I am supposed to increase?

This looks like a quota or a billing issues. To be honest I don't know the exact recipe but I would suggest checking

https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/AI-ML/Limited-request-per-minute-5-RPM-for-Gemini-models/m-p/758263/highlight/true (look for answer posted by Poala)

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/quotas


